# Broken link call method?

Tags: objective-c

I'm having trouble again with Objective-C

I'm trying to call a method but Xcode seems not to know it..

The problem comes from :

```
NSMutableArray *examsToExport;
NSMutableArray *examsToExport2;
```

There is the code extracted from the .h:

```
- (void)examSaving:(NSMutableArray**)examsToExport withExport2:(NSMutableArray**)examsToExport2;
```

now from the .m:

```
[self examSaving:&examsToExport: &examsToExport2];
```

After on, inside this method I'm working with 2 NSMutableArrays
That's why, I declared them as NSMArray** (so I don't have to return them right ?)
But, Xcode won't let me do so,

```
    while (i < [&examsToExport count] - 1)
```

Xcode:

```
Receiver type 'NSMutableArray**'is not 'id' or interface pointer, consider casting it to 'id'
```

Could you help me on this ?

Comment: `[self examSaving:&examsToExport :&examsToExport2];`? But that's not how it's recommended to declare methods in Objective-C. It's should be more verbose: `- (void)examSaving:(NSMutableArray**)examsToExport withExport2: (NSMutableArray**)examsToExport2;` (or something like that, I didn't understood your thing).

Comment: I'm like really new to objectiveC, I might have done some mistakes for sure

Answer (score 1):

call the method like this. Coma isn't the proper argument separator.

```
 [self examSaving:&examsToExport:&examsToExport2];
```

and then I would use:

```
while (i < [*examsToExport count] - 1){


}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, but you are trying to call method `count` on the address of the obejct `examsToExport`. That would generate error **Bad receiver type 'NSMutableArray'**. What is your reasoning behind this recommendation?

Comment: Oh I see, it's in the *OTHER* method, because there is only a reference passed. My bad, rtfm +1 as a kind sportsmanship. The OP seems unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have to call that method like this:

```
[self examSaving:&examsToExport:&examsToExport2];
```

Not like this:

```
[self examSaving:&examsToExport, &examsToExport2];
```

And for the second question, no need to dereference it, just use it without the `&`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks.. I'm used to C language.. and, would that work ? I mean, will it work like I had returned my two arrays ?